# Does Google Test Have the Concept of "Unexpected Success"?

Tags: c, testing, googletest

Suppose there's a deficiency in my code that I don't have time to address yet.  I do have time to write a test but I don't want it to "break the build".

I would like to write a test that will show as an "Expected Failure" until I address the issue at which point it would changed to "Unexpected Success".  At that point I could change it into a standard test that I expect to pass and *would* break the build if it failed.

Is there any way to do this in Google Test?  `DISABLED_` tests don't really cut it because they aren't run.  I am thinking of something more like [Twisted's `.todo` attribute for Python](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/development/policy/test-standard.html#testing-new-functionality) except for C and Google Test specifically.

Comment: I do not know such a feature, but would like to have it too. As a workaround one can mark those tests `DISABLED_` and run them seperated in the build. But that means to run every testhost in the build twice.